YARP problems when reverse proxying to a different IIS server using webforms
I'm trying to set up YARP as a reverse proxy on a linux container to allow moving away from legacy asp.net forms.
I get served responses from the IIS server but the static routes don't seem to be accessible and the mime types are being stripped from all CSS / JS files
There's a UrlRewrite redirecting all /static-x.y.z to /static in the IIS server. For most of the files I do get the file in the response but without mime type. For others the routing seems incorrect as I get a html page in response ( for example in favicon.ico )
So far I've made sure that all authorization sections in web.config are set to users="*". I've removed the no-sniff header temporarily and that helped with some of the files but not all, Javascript is still not executing because libraries can't be found
I'm hoping someone else has had this problem and can point me in the right direction as I've been googling for several days but most issues I come across are hosting static files on the same server as YARP

Does this issue only occur in Linux environment？Are there any error messages or log information to locate the problem?

In this case it turns out that the nginx setup for the cluster was incorrect. I needed to remove the rewrite-url annotation from the linux ingress and add it to the windows ingress with a target of /$2 so that it would pass the path in both cases
